# How to scroll to the end of the page with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to scroll to the end of a facebook page so that I can load all the posts, how can I do that with selenium while the page is still loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python I would do this :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

this is somewhat always works for me.

Comment: but I should replace scrollTop with Bottom in my case